# CSS Styles applying outside of the DIV where they are assigned

Tags: css, styles

In my style sheet, I have overridden the style of H1 and H2 with the following code:
And in my HTML, I have applied that style to a DIV that contains an H1 tag.

However, this style is also applying to H1 and H2 tags AFTER the div in question.

Replicated here: http://jsfiddle.net/89gkQ/1/

Why is the style applying outside of the div where it's applied, and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CSS, the comma doesn't work like it does in English:

```
.featuredtitle h1, h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

That code is equivalent to this code:

```
.featuredtitle h1 {
  color: red;
}

h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

Which isn't what you want. The comma just allows you to write multiple selectors, so you want to be a bit more verbose:

```
.featuredtitle h1, .featuredtitle h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/89gkQ/2/**

Comment: Thank you, I knew it had to be something simple!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
.featuredtitle h1,h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#a00;
}
```

You should write the following instead:

```
.featuredtitle h1, .featuredtitle h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#a00;
}
```

The comma starts a new selector, which in this case made the style apply to all H2 tags, regardless of where they are.